# parseInt html string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to perform simple calculations using jQuery but I'm getting NaN as result.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).on('click','.button-group button:not(.done)', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var votevalue = $(this).data('votevalue');
        var image_id = $('.mainimage').data('image_id');
        var votes = $('.mainimage').data('numvotes');
        var totalscore = $('.mainimage').data('totalscore');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '?a=vote',
                data: {
                    "votevalue" : votevalue,
                    "image_id" : image_id
                },
                success: function(){
                    var votes = parseInt(votes);
                    votes++;
                    var average = ((parseInt(totalscore) + parseInt(votevalue)) / votes);
                    $('#vote-incremenet').html(votes);
                    $('#display-average').html(average);
                    $('#display-average').show();
                    $('.button-group button').addClass('done');
                }
        }); // end ajax
}); // end click
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your `NaN` issue, shouldn't you also be storing the new `votes` value back into `$('.mainimage').data('numvotes')`? Otherwise when another button is clicked it will use the old `numvotes` value for its calculation.

Comment: No all buttons are deactivated (.addClass('done')) after user first choice until next image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use parseInt, be sure to pass `(parseInt(str), radix)`to prevent an automatic conversion to some other base.

> If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16
>   (hexadecimal).
>
> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight
>   (octal). This feature is non-standard, and some implementations
>   deliberately do not support it (instead using the radix 10).
>
> For this
>   reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.

(**[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**)

In your case, `parseInt(varname, 10);`

---

If the issue persists, it is likely you are passing an incorrect value to one of the variables you are using for calculation.

---

**EDIT:**

`var votes = parseInt(votes);` inside the call-back makes it a local variable. Hence,it has lost the value it was given outside. Do not redeclare it within the callback.

Comment: Another thing I found out is that I was getting NaN when performing the calculation in the callback function. But when I moved the same calculation to before the ajax it displayed the numbers.

Comment: @user1683645 Try the **same** code you posted, with `var votes = parseInt(votes);` changed to just `votes = parseInt(votes);` in the success call-back.